# QField and pictures sharing solutions

Tags: qgis, qfield

I'm currently working on a massive GIS for an archaeological mission and looking for a picture cloud/sharing solution.

The picture inventory is an online PostgreSQL table accessible via QField running on 4 android tablets with 4G connection.

My goal is the following :
on field, pictures will be taken using QField and stored on SD card storage using a similar name folder on each tablets.
Every evening all pictures taken in the different tablets should be synchronized automatically using WiFi on a shared drive so that every picture taken with every tablets should be available locally on every tablets on SD cards the next day.

So I was thinking about creating local WiFi network with a router and hook up a NAS server as shared drive for this purpose. Then using a syncronizing app to upload/download pictures to and from the NAS every evening.

At first I was thinking of doing all of it online through FTP/HTTP but I doubt we will have a good enough internet access for this at our hotel (remote place) and it would consume too much data to do it through 4G.

Any of you had to do similar projects? Any better ideas on how to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Sounds like a sensible solution to me, but definitely set it and try it out to smooth out bugs/work flow before you go to your remote location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [QFieldCloud](https://qfield.cloud/)?
It can help you managing data collected by different operator and devices with a cloud-based solution.
Sometimes some workarounds are needed but it works. I don't know if the free plan fits your needs. If you're working with QGIS is a good choice.

Comment: Mergin (formerly Input) would be an option too, but it wouldn't be free. See https://merginmaps.com

Answer (score 0):

Syncthing (https://syncthing.net/) could be a silent companion in the background. It can also synchronize over a local network.